# Writing our own iterator for a java hashtable with nodes

Tags: java, iterator, nodes, hashtable

For our java class, we are expected to implement our own iterator in our SymbolTable class (essentially just a hashtable). I am done with the SymbolTable class, but not the iterator class. I am not sure how to build the constructor, as well as how to properly fill out the hasNext(); method.
For reference, here is the inner node class:

```
private class Node {
    // nodes used to build the linked lists used in a
    // separate chaining hash table
    private String key;
    private Object data;
    private Node next;

    private Node(String k, Object d, Node n) {
        key = k;
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
}

private Node table[];
private int tableSize;
//Used in iterator
```

Now, here is what I have so far for the iterator:

```
public class STIterator implements Iterator<String> {
    // An iterator that iterates through the keys in the table
    // each call to next returns the next key in the table
    Node head;
    Node current;
    int pos = 0;

    public STIterator() {
        current = table[0];

    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    public String next() {
        // have to move down to location i+1 usually
        // move to next element in table thats not null
        // PRE: hasNext()
        if (hasNext()) {
            String data = (String) current.data;
            current = current.next;
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

So essentially, this iterator scans through a hashtable which holds certain words (scanned in from a book). So, we want the iterator to loop through the table until it finds data (an object, d) that is not null. Meaning a specific "slot" in the hashtable that includes a word (which is given by key in the node class)/

Comment: What exactly is your question, that is, what is your iterator doing (or not doing)? What are you unsure about regarding the constructor?

Comment: Yes sorry, new to SO. I need the iterator to go through the String keys in my hashtable. I know I start the iterator at the beginning (hence starting at table[0], but I am unsure how to write the constructor to correctly build the iterator, as well as use the next and hasNext methods to manually iterate (meaning not using utils java has given us).

Comment: Let's say you have a hash table where tableSize is 2 and table[0] and table[1] each has a node where next is null. Does your iterator return each of those two nodes in turn?

Comment: It is supposed to call the next until it finds an element at that specific data. So, it should cycle until it finds a value(Which is our String key), so it should exit the iteration if none are found. I have it simply returning null.

Comment: You are iterating only through the list which is on the first bucket. You need also to iterate over buckets once you reached the end of the list from current bucket

Answer (score 0):

I suppose at present your code looks like this:

```
public class SymbolTable {
...
   private class Node {
   ...
   }
   public class STIterator implements Iterator<String> {
   ...
   }
}
```

Let's add a `main` method in `SymbolTable`:

```
   public static void main(String... args) {
      SymbolTable map = new SymbolTable();
      map.put("foo", "foo data");
      map.put("bar", "bar data");
      
      Iterator<String> i = map.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(i.next());
      }
   }
```

Now you have some runnable code, and you can ask questions about it. Please try that and edit your question with your new code and any compilation errors, exceptions or undesired behaviour your program has.

Answer (score 0):

This is a genuinely tricky problem, and I don't know any better way to really answer it than to give you the answer.  I'm assuming you don't need to support `remove()`; if you do, I'll leave that part as an exercise.

```
// FYI: this class doesn't have to be, and arguably shouldn't be, public
public class STIterator implements Iterator<String> {
    // An iterator that iterates through the keys in the table
    // each call to next returns the next key in the table
    Node current = null;
    int pos = 0;

    public STIterator() {}

    public boolean hasNext() {
      while (current == null && pos < table.length) {
        current = table[pos++];
      }
      return current != null;
    }

    public String next() {
      if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
      String k = current.key;
      current = current.next;
      return k;
    }
}
```

This is based on the assumption that you're trying to iterate over the entire table.  If you're looking for a specific key, you possibly shouldn't be using an iterator at all, just a loop.